How to automate a series of similar IF statements
I have a series of IF statements that I think should be automated into a shorter piece of code but I'm not sure how to go about doing it. Here's an example of the code:
var supplier_kw_per_rack = 2;

if (kw_value === '1+kW'){ var kw_integer = 1; var ongoing_kw = 350; }
if (kw_value === '2+kW'){ var kw_integer = 2; var ongoing_kw = 350; }
if (kw_value === '3+kW'){ var kw_integer = 3; var ongoing_kw = 700; }
if (kw_value === '4+kW'){ var kw_integer = 4; var ongoing_kw = 700; }
if (kw_value === '5+kW'){ var kw_integer = 5; var ongoing_kw = 1050; }
if (kw_value === '6+kW'){ var kw_integer = 6; var ongoing_kw = 1050; }
if (kw_value === '7+kW'){ var kw_integer = 7; var ongoing_kw = 1400; }
if (kw_value === '8+kW'){ var kw_integer = 8; var ongoing_kw = 1400; }
if (kw_value === '9+kW'){ var kw_integer = 9; var ongoing_kw = 1750; }
if (kw_value === '10+kW'){ var kw_integer = 10; var ongoing_kw = 1750; }
if (kw_value === '11+kW'){ var kw_integer = 11; var ongoing_kw = 2100; }
if (kw_value === '12+kW'){ var kw_integer = 12; var ongoing_kw = 2100; }
if (kw_value === '13+kW'){ var kw_integer = 13; var ongoing_kw = 2450; }
if (kw_value === '14+kW'){ var kw_integer = 14; var ongoing_kw = 2450; }
if (kw_value === '15+kW'){ var kw_integer = 15; var ongoing_kw = 2800; }
if (kw_value === '16+kW'){ var kw_integer = 16; var ongoing_kw = 2800; }
if (kw_value === '17+kW'){ var kw_integer = 17; var ongoing_kw = 3150; }
if (kw_value === '18+kW'){ var kw_integer = 18; var ongoing_kw = 3150; }
if (kw_value === '19+kW'){ var kw_integer = 19; var ongoing_kw = 3500; }
if (kw_value === '20+kW'){ var kw_integer = 20; var ongoing_kw = 3500; }
if (kw_value === '21+kW'){ var kw_integer = 21; var ongoing_kw = 3850; }
if (kw_value === '22+kW'){ var kw_integer = 22; var ongoing_kw = 3850; }

Some context:

kw_value is the value of a selectbox value that's been selected. The CMS doesn't have a value attribute with just the number, so I can only match it to the IF statement by the value of what's outputted once selected
kw_integer is just that - a clean integer of the selected selectbox option.
ongoing_kw goes up by a fixed 350 for every iteration of the value defined in supplier_kw_per_rack. In this instance, it's every 2 racks, but if the value of supplier_kw_per_rack is changed to 4, the value of ongoing_kw needs only go up by the fixed 350 figure every multiple of 4 for kw_value/integer

I've got it working to this point where I don't need to explicitly run the IF statement for each combination of selectbox value and I've found a way to automate the kw integer variable that is born from this statement. However I'm struggling now with finding a way to make the value of ongoing_kw go up by 350, depending on whether the kw value or kw integer is a multiple of supplier_kw_per_rack. Here's an example of where I'm at:
if (kw_value === kw_value){ var kw_integer = Number(kw_value.substring(0, kw_value.length - 3)); var ongoing_kw = 350; }```


Add a function that gets a number and return the object you want and call the function in the select.

In order to solve this issue, let's break it down first:
you have an input kw_value, and based on the initial integer in this input and  the value of supplier_kw_per_rack, you want to assign values to kw_integer and ongoing_kw.
Let's say you can get the integer in the beginning of the kw_value, let's call it initial_integer. the initial_integer value can be assigned to the kw_integer variable. ongoing_kw seems to be (((initial_integer - 1) // supplier_kw_per_rack) + 1) * 350. Divide initial_integer - 1 by supplier_kw_per_rack and only get the integer part add 1 to it. Then multiply that by 350.
when you reduce 1 from the initial_integer, it gets a bit easier to think about
   reduce 1    divide by supplier_kw_per_rack       add 1      multiply by 350
1     ->    0               ->                  0    ->    1          ->        350
2     ->    1               ->                  0    ->    1          ->        350
3     ->    2               ->                  1    ->    2          ->        700
4     ->    3               ->                  1    ->    2          ->        700
5     ->    4               ->                  2    ->    3          ->        1050
6     ->    5               ->                  2    ->    3          ->        1050

so, in conclusion, here will be your code
let kw_value = <input>
let supplier_kw_per_rack = 2
var kw_integer = Number(kw_value.substring(0, kw_value.length - 3)) // like you've wrote
var ongoing_kw = (((kw_integer - 1) // supplier_kw_per_rack) + 1) * 350


Thank you so much, this looks like it's working on my side and all systems are go!

I think the supplier_kw_per_rack is dynamic so you can use this function and get the result.
This function result will be display in the div tag with id of display.
You can show many results.
<div id="display"></div>
<script>
    const getOngoing_kw = function(kw_value, supplier_kw_per_rack, fixed = 350) {
    // I assume your input value is a string like '12+kW'. 
    // convert any input to string type
    let inputString = '' + kw_value;
    // Get the number out of the string.
    let num = inputString.match(/\d+/)[0];

    // Create the iteration number
    const iteration = Math.ceil(num / supplier_kw_per_rack);
    
    let display = document.getElementById('display');
    // Return the Object 
    let pElemnt = document.createElement("p");
    pElemnt.innerText = 'kw integer is '+ num + ', kw value is ' + kw_value + ' and kw cost is '+ iteration * fixed;
    display.appendChild(pElemnt);
    }

    // test the function
    getOngoing_kw('12+kW', 2);
</script>


Thank you, this is an interesting approach as it means the data only needs to be amended in a few key places for it to still function correctly. I'm struggling with getting the data to display with the variables outside of the function though. Something like this after the closing bracket of the function test that you wrote:
console.log('kw integer is ' + kw_integer)
console.log('kw value is ' + kw_value)
console.log('kw cost is ' + ongoing_kw)
I've declared those variables with a baseline value of 0 at the top of the file. But the numbers don't update, based on the changing kw_value.

Still I did not got exactly what you want.  Where you want to display the data and how the displayed data should look like.
If you provide an example it will be helpful to write better code.
I change the code based on my understanding.
